# JQuery extract form input name and add it as a class to the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of inputs in some forms and I would like to add unique classes to each input based on the input name.

So for example this:

```
<input name="first_name">
```

... would become this using JQuery:

```
<input name="first_name" class="first-name">
```

I've searched around but could not find much reference to extracting the input name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: Might need to add a .replace(/_/g, '-') in there to translate the underscores to dashes, as in his example.  Otherwise looks good.